# Is there any command or way to find out the location of my JUnit?

Tags: junit

i have a MacBook Pro and have downloaded java version 1.8 and selenium also. But im unable to find JUnit. Can i get the command to check the location of my JUnit. I have tried using a code to check whether JUnit is installed and the output is successful.

Comment: why do you require JUnit's location?

Comment: JUnit is a library. It can be anywhere. Normally, you simply use something like Maven or Gradle to automatically add it to your project without having to worry about locations. Selenium has to integrate itself a bit into your system, but JUnit doesn't.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz so if i add Gradle in my code library, JUnit will automatically come?

Comment: No. It means that when you understand the available tools and spend the time **learning** how they work then they can do certain things for you. This is not magic; where a wizard swipes his wand and miracles happen. These are tools that have certain features; all of that nicely documented. You can't rush into using such a multitude of tools expecting that all of that works *without* investing **hours** of intensive study on your end.

Comment: Maven/Gradle are build tools. They take care of dependecy management and many other stuff in your projects. One of the things you can do with them is using them to make sure that JUnit is part of your project. This means you don't have to search .jar files, etc. You simply tell Maven/Gradle to add Junit, Version X, and it's there.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit is not part of the standard JDK content; same for selenium.

Thus: you have to **do** something to pull the JUnit jar to your system. Either by downloading it manually yourself; or by using a build system like Maven or Gradle that can take care about resolving "dependencies" and downloading required artifacts automatically for you.

But in order to locate jar files on your system, you can simply turn to **find** command, like:

```
find / -type f -name "*.jar"
```

which should list you JAR *files* existing in your file system. You can read [here](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-find-files-via-the-os-x-terminal/) about this and other tools that help you *find* files in your file system using the command line.

Comment: I used the above command, but the results are Permission denied for all the file locations.

Comment: Try running the command as root; using "sudo" for example. And hint: learn about the tools you are using.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt that the command is actually worth using. If you need a dependency, then have Maven/Gradle/etc. take care of it. You don't need to know where the file actually resides on your hard drive. Going through random .jar files in your file system is just a way to jar file hell. What you WANT is to express "Dear Tool, make sure Junit in Version 4.12 is in my project"  and then start using JUnit.. You do not want to care about .jar files.

Comment: My point is more about: understanding such aspects. Therefore I told him to look into build systems. But still: one should understand *how* such things work in the end. Figuring locations in the file system is one part of that. In that sense: knowing about jar files is important. Locating them might be important sometimes, too. What I mean is: "you dont care about something" is LEVEL 2. First comes LEVEL 1 which goes "you understand that something". And my answer is meant to give some push to work on that "understanding" side.